# Question on badges

Tags: support, badges, moderators

I am not able to understand the badging process of this site 
for eg :

Nice Answer     Answer score of 10 or more

By what I understand from the above, anytime I get an score of 10 I should be getting a Nice answer badge , while I do not !!!!

Not too deep into this but always feel nice to see the orange pumping up next to the name :)

Answer (score 3):

According to your bio, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/582/rao?tab=answers, page you (currently) don't have any answers with a score of 10. You do have one at 9, though.

Comment: Ha, it just hit 10. He should get the badge shortly.

Comment: Maybe rao was confusing number of votes with rep points.  1 vote = 10 pts, but 10 votes are needed for this badge, not 10 rep pts, but I doubt it...probably just a time delay.

Comment: Sooo far off topic, but this is meta :) congratulations @mike on your/the sites first gold badge!

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't know it was the first gold badge!